# Java Script - P2P Video Connect - When i open full screen, see to my screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video-streaming, p2p

I Have a problem. I dont have idea how can i fix this.

By the way my English could be not enought. I'm sorry for this.

We are making a system. Its about two people conversesion as live screen. We have used peer js.

I will send you a picture. We maked this.

[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IULu3.jpg)

When i open other person's screen. I want to see our screen in right place. Its like skype.

Source : http://peerjs.com/

Thank You Guys..

Comment: Could you post what you do using Java Script?

Comment: Sir, i send the pictures as three part.

https://i.hizliresim.com/gWR1ZL.png -
https://i.hizliresim.com/Mv4ML6.png -
https://i.hizliresim.com/Q7GdZA.png -

https://i.hizliresim.com/kWRPB7.png